# Bash: Date Input with Spaces

Tags: bash, date

I'm trying to rename a bunch of files I was given in the format of `dd mmm yyyy.csv` (that's `mmm` as in Jan, Feb, Mar...). How would I use `date` in bash to rename the files to `yyyy-mm-dd.csv`?

I tried this:

```
$ date "27 Mar 2008 +%Y-%m-%d"
date: invalid date '27 Mar 2008 +%Y-%m-%d'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ date -d '27 Mar 2008' +'%Y-%m-%d'
2008-03-27
```

Comment: Thanks @karakfa. Worked for me!